# data template in MVC :- how to define constant in javascript from the c# code

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, datatemplate

Are their any feature exist something like data template. i have a js file for my project who linked in all page using i linked them in master page.

I want to define their some constant who are define in a c# class called Globals. how i can configure or access them in my js file i used in my project.

i need a thing that when code is load on client system that some variable on the js file set from class c#.

suppose i define them in the code i write in Razor

var name @glboals.appName;

but if i define them in the file that they never render them as  they render in the views.

so are their any way to applied constant in js file when file is standalone and not embedded in views.

so any sollution for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
<html>    
    <!-- blah blah bla -->    
    <script>    
        var myFirstGlobalVar = '@Namespace.Class.Variable';    
    </script>    
</html>
...
```

**BTW**, if you say MasterPage and then you show code with `@` we just don't know what are you talking about, it's a good thing to mention the version as a tag.

**MasterPages** are for WebForms and MVC 1 and 2, **LayoutViews** are for MVC 3

---

If you want to have this in a static file ... well, it's a static file, it does not get processed, so all you will see is the exact code you wrote.

To handle such things you need to process this file dynamically, so, lets add a Controller called `DynamicScripts` and an Action called `JsVariables` and add a normal `return View();`

use that view as a plain Javascript file that you set up variables, and you can pass any Model

Now, in your `global.asax`create a new rule:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CustomJs", // Route name
    "Js/Variables", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "DynamicScripts", action = "JsVariables", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

and in your `html` jus add the line:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Js/Variables")" type="text/javascript" />
```

There are more ways to do this, like using the `RegisterStartUpScript`, but the trick above (though I use it for **CSS** and not JavaScript) is what I use the most.

Comment: only if it's a dynamic file, not static... for example you call `/ScriptsController/Action` and you have changed that `ContentType` to `text/javascript`.

Comment: all jscript code i have written in js offcouse it was static. well bugai13 really describe a nice trick to suite for this porblem well thanks

Comment: he did? but I said the same in the first place, that's what the first code is all about ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can define script like this in views master, and use config in each view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Config = {};
    Config.appName = '<%= glboals.appName %>';     
</script>
```

It's mvc2 example, you can do the same in razor.